# Is there a way to update the legend to the value of a variable within the chart.events?

Tags: highcharts, legend

I am plotting a 3D line chart over time. Each time the count changes at the end of the loop, a new point is plotted for each series. Is there a way to set the value of the legend as the value of count in my example code? The count represents hours since the start of an experiment, so being able to display this is necessary. Thanks!

```
events: {
    load: function() {
        var thischart = this;
        for (i = 0; i < allpoints.length; i++) {
            thischart.addSeries({
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                data: [0, 0, 0]
            }, false)
            thischart.redraw(false);
        }
        setInterval(function() {

            if (count >= max_data_length) {
                if (!pause_at_end) {
                    for (i = 0; i < allpoints.length; i++) {
                        thischart.series[i + marker_series_length].setData([0, 0, 0], false);
                    }
                    thischart.redraw(false);
                    count = 1;
                } else {
                    is_paused = true;
                    document.getElementById('pauseit').value = "Unpause";
                }
            }
            if (!is_paused) {
                for (i = 0; i < allpoints.length; i++) {
                    if (allpoints[i].length > count) {
                        thischart.series[i + marker_series_length].addPoint([
                            allpoints[i][count][0], allpoints[i][count][2], allpoints[i][count][1]
                        ], false);
                    }
                }
                thischart.redraw(false);
                count = count + 4;
            }
        }, 10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `series.update` method to set new data and change the series name in legend:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var counter = 0,
                series = this.series[0];

            setInterval(function() {
                counter++;

                series.update({
                    data: getRandomData(),
                    name: 'Name ' + counter
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7bq21tak/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ppotaczek! This pointed me in the right direction. I used chart.update instead to update the subtitle. Here is the code I used:

```
    chart.update({
          chart: {
                  inverted: false,
                  polar: false
                  },
                  subtitle: {
                  style: {
                  fontSize: '20px'
                          },
                  text:'Day:'+ countdays
                          }
                  });
```